# "URLs Amigables" - .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Necesito ayuda con URLs amigables utilizando el archivo *.htaccess* de Apache. Exploré varias publicaciones y ninguna me ha resultado, porque necesito **dos parámetros**.

Por ejemplo:
`https://api.mysite.com/api/url/create`

**/api/ es un directorio**

Se tratará como:
`https://api.mysite.com/api/url.php?act={create, delete, etc}`

**PS**: El parámetro 1 sería url o cualquiera, que abre el archivo parametro1.php, el segundo sería create o cualquiera que especifica el parametro GET al archivo.

Comment: ¿Es `url` un valor fijo o puede cambiar?

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que hacer algo así:

```
RewriteRule ^api/url/(.*) api/url.php?act=$1
```

Lo que hace esta linea es mandar una regla, o escribir una regla 'RewriteRule' en donde busque la direccion **`api/url.php?act=$1`**
 donde **`act=`** es la variable que vas a obtener, y **`$1`** es el valor de la variable (tiene que comenzar con **`$`** porque eso le indica a .htacccess que el valor será una variable), entonces todo esto lo va a susituir por la direccion que quieras, en este caso `api/url/(.*)`, en donde `(.*)` sera el valor de la variable en la nueva url ,en este caso puedes ser cualquier valor, número o letra.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar con un poco más de detalle lo que hace esa línea y por qué "hay que hacer algo así"?

Comment: mira ahora brother, ya le puse una explicacion, sino entiendes me avisas

Comment: Si quieres dos parámetros simplemente utiliza dos agrupaciones de regex en lugar de una y reescribelo la url  usando dos variables: `RewriteRule ^api/([^/]*)/(.*) api/$1.php?act=$2`. No hay necesidad de insultar.

Comment: No entendieron mal lo que dije, no fue un insulto,  creo que me exprese mal, pero mi intencion no era insultar, bueno, lo siento